# Как выполнить функцию через определенное время?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть программа на python 3.8 с графическим интерфейсом на Tkinter. При нажатии на кнопку должно выполняться 2 функции, но одна чуть позже другой. Как вторую функцию поставить на таймер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import time

def func1():
    {do something}

def func2():
    time.sleep(5) #Так же можно использовать float (5.4)
    {do sometging}
```